# ¿Como ver la sub-regex o sub expresion regular dentro de un grupo de una expresion regular mas grande en python?

Tags: python, regex

Tengo esta regex `regex='^(([^\n\s\d])+([5-7])){2,5}.htm$'`
Puedo ver cuantos grupos existen en esa regex con:

```py
import re
patron=re.compile(rf'{regex}')
grupos=patron.groups # Esto devuelve 3
```

Pero ahora yo quiero ver la sub-regex que esta en el grupo(2), **OJO, NO** quiero hacer match o search para luego ver el el grupo(2) en el resultado del match. Yo lo que quiero ver es el`([^\n\s\d])` o `[^\n\s\d]` literal, quiero saber si existe algun atributo que asi como dice cuantos grupos existen en la regex, asi mismo diga cual es la sub-regex detras del grupo n.

Quiero algo así como:

```py
patron.regexGroup(2)
# y devuelva
[^\n\s\d]
```

Obviamente regexGroup no existe dentro de re, y de eso se trata mi pregunta, quiero saber si existe un atributo o función que me devuelva la lógica de la regex de un grupo en especifico.

Comment: Falto el ejemplo: texto de entrada y como quieres el resultado.

Answer (score 2):

No existe una forma con `re`. El objeto devuelto por `re.compile()` tiene sólo estos métodos: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re-objects.

Además, en expresiones regulares, no existe el concepto de "*subgrupo*". En tu patrón hay 3 grupos, por más que el 2do y el 3ro entén incluidos dentro del primero. El orden en que se numeran los grupos es siempre de izquierda a derecha, en el orden en que aparece cada apertura de paréntesis `(`. Y cada grupo no está considerado como padre/hijo, son todos grupos con la misma jerarquía.

En otros lenguajes tampoco es común encontrar lo que estás buscando... Personalmente no se me ocurren usos prácticos que requieran que se devuelva el string usado para generar el patrón.

Para obtener el resultado que estás buscando, deberías procesar directamente el string que genera el patrón.. un trabajo complicado que me imagino está fuera del alcance de lo que buscás (o quizás exista algún módulo que ya procese expresiones regulares, pero desconozco). Una primera aproximación sería obtener todos los grupos de paréntesis en un string, pero luego tendrías que descartar los paréntesis que no forman grupos `(?: )`, `(?= )`, etc. o reglas especiales donde se tomen como caracteres `\(`, `[(]`, etc.